# Error 400: invalid_request Missing required parameter: scope

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, google-authentication

from last two days i am stuck on this issue, everything was working fine on my local environment but on production its giving the above error,

**My web application can be accessed through vpn only, so do u think this might be the issue ?**

```
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['openid','profile', 'email']
}));
```

The openid i have added for a hit and try method but that also didn't work, previously in scope only email and profile was there, my google startegy is below

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        // options for strategy
        callbackURL: `${baseUrl}/auth/google/redirect`,
        clientID: process.env.PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.PASSPORT_CLIENTSECRET
    }, (accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: any, done: any) => {
        //code
    })
```

I am using passport-google-oauth20 npm package for google login, any help will be appreciated

Comment: show me the version of `connect` module in production

Comment: connect module ? i am not using any such module, passport ,passport-google-oauth20 thats the module i am using,  "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",

Comment: install this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi but why ? wont it work without it ? as it is working on localhost

Comment: Hello! Well, seems that, during the HTTP requests and redirects, for some reason, the HTTP request that should contain the `scope` GET parameter does not contain this parameter as expected. To debug the issue the first thing to do is, with dev tools, get the exact HTTP request that have, as response, a status 400. Please provide that information here so we can help you.

Comment: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=<URL>google%2Fredirect&scope=openid%20profile%20email&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>., exactly the same thing i coming on localhost but not working on production

Answer (score 0):

Try change this:

```
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['openid','profile', 'email']
}));
```

For this:

```
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { 
    scope: ['openid','profile', 'email'] }));
```

it worked for me...